# Update entire table based on parameter of another table in a matching field

Tags: mysql, sql

I've my table `user_data` that has over 8k records. Then I have my table `Geo_location`. Both tables join on the `member_num` column

`Geo_location` has a column called `public` that should match the table `user_data` column `acceptinClients`. Its an `INT` 0 or 1

I am having some data consistency problem and not all record match. I know how to do a long winded fetch and do one by one update in PHP if they dont match.

But I was wondering if there is a way to create a SQL query that will loop through all records  in `Geo_location - public` and update them with whatever value is in `user_data - acceptinClients`

Is there a way to do that or am i asking too much? if so, how?
i have been reading around but cant find a simple solution for my problem or dont understand them

Comment: Voting to leave open based on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139961/whats-the-policy-on-closing-unique-questions-with-overlapping-but-non-duplicat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand the problem, but isn't

```
UPDATE Geo_location AS g 
JOIN users_data AS u ON u.member_num = g.member_num 
SET g.public = ud.acceptinClients
```

correct?